# How to dismiss flutter Get library dialog?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am showing a dialogue with [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) library and I want to dismiss automatically after a few seconds with `Future`. But I found no suitable function for that. So how do I dismiss a `get` dialogue after showing it?

code:

```
Get.dialog(Center(
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Text('Hello'),
    ),
  )); // how to dismiss? Like Get.Dismiss().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for dismiss dialog try using :

```
Get.back();
```

or

```
navigator.pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not used `Get`, but if you really want to do that thing, that I can suggest my way of doing it.

So, we will be using [Flutter AlerDialog Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html), which works the same, that is popping up the dialog, and you can always edit the content.

Now let us do these things:

- Creating a dialog
- Pop Up when the button is clicked
- Auto dismiss the dialog

This will help you organize your solution. And we will be using `Future` only.

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {

  // set up the button
  Widget okButton = FlatButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () { },
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("My title"),
    content: Text("This is my message."),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

This method will pop-up the dialog, and then autodismiss, the dialog:

```
void _ourAutoDismissDialog(BuildContext context){
    
   //Calling out showdialog method
   showAlertDialog(context);

   //Auto dismissing after the 2 seconds
   // You can set the time as per your requirements in Duration
   // This will dismiss the dialog automatically after the time you 
   // have mentioned
   Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), (){
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
   });
}
```

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () => _ourAutoDismissDialog(context)
  child: Text('Hello')
)
```

*To dismiss the dialog, we need to do back operation, and we do it via `Navigator.of(context).pop()`*

This is the result we get after implementing the above:

[image: Resultant]

Comment: Its great. But one of the reason I am using `Get` library is because I do not have access to `buildcontext` . So how can I pop when no saved buildcontext is available? or perhaps we can get the context or similar from `Get` library.

Comment: anyway, I tried this: `Navigator.of(Get.context).pop();` it showed no error but dialogue was not dissmissed.